# Non-gaming gaming console questions -- allowed?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

Should non-game related gaming console questions be allowed? Some question might be "Does Blu-Ray work for XBox 360"?

Should these be allowed because they are a gaming console or are they better suited for the electronic gadget proposal? (or even super user)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that [SuperUser will take consoles-being-used-as-a-PC](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/3804/should-questions-about-using-a-gaming-console-as-a-pc-be-allowed) questions, e.g., installing Linux on your PS3.  Console hardware questions aren't on-topic there outside a PC scope — installing Linux drivers for your optical drive is OK, asking whether the drive can play Blu-Rays is not.  Like Juan I think we can handle the rest of the questions related to consoles.

Answer (score 15):

I think it's a borderline topic, I'd say yes because it's related to consoles (which would make it off topic on super user) and consoles are exclusive to gaming.

Comment: note that PC hardware questions should belong on Super User