# Are questions about setting up consoles/PCs on topic?

Tags: discussion, gaming-hardware, faq

I've just seen [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/162097/wii-to-vga-no-signal-floating-message) on Super User and was reluctant to mention that this site existed as a potential place where the question could be asked.

There's at least one hardware question already on the site [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/236/refurbishing-loose-xbox360-controller) so they are at least tolerated.

So - should we allow questions about how to connect consoles to monitors, older consoles to modern TVs etc.?

Whatever the stance it should be clearly documented in the FAQ.

Comment: I think some of the general rules from [here](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/253/hardware-questions/257#257) probably apply well. So, for example, consoles to monitors would be on-topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think as long as it's exclusive to gaming it should be on topic, I gave a similar response [here](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96/non-gaming-gaming-console-questions-allowed/101#101)