# Are questions regarding game server administration on topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

Many multi-player games allow you to run public or private servers on your own.  Are questions about the administration of these servers applicable for this site?

Examples would be something like - "How do I adjust the map rotation on my TF2 server?", or, "Where can I find a good source for plug-ins on my XXX server?"

Edit: Given this [question and answer](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307/are-questions-about-setting-up-consoles-pcs-on-topic), it would suggest that topics like this are still on topic - but it's not 100% clear.

Answer (score 5):

I would say yes, for the same reasons given there. However, the ones that end up off-topic here would end up on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com), not Super User.

To my knowledge, the majority of these questions deal less with the servers themselves, and more configuring the settings of the games and how they are played. Which sounds on-topic to me. But it doesn't hurt to think to yourself, "How much of my real question is founded in the game rather than server management?", when you ask these questions.

Comment: There's two options, either we accept these questions, or we set up an SE for just Game Servers. Seeing as I don't think Server Fault would find them on-topic.

Comment: @ArdaXi I don't think Server Fault will find game servers on-topic, no (and I think we're comfortable fitting them here). But I don't expect every single question about a gaming server to be related to the actual game. Unless gaming servers are that much different than the kinds of servers those sysadmins work on (I've never had to work on a gaming server myself).

Comment: Setting an SE only for Game Servers I think will not get critical mass easily, but this is a personal opinion. For me we can keep this type of questions and let see how the situation evolves

Comment: @user59 For me what would be the best (although I am new to A.SE) is to have if it's more dealing with the plugins/mods/settings, here, but for more IPs, routers, server location, etc. it should go on Server Fault, but it might be more difficult for newcomers to understand the difference.