# PS3 Blu-ray Questions

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, gaming-hardware

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Non-gaming gaming console questions — allowed?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96/non-gaming-gaming-console-questions-allowed)

Would they be on topic?  Technically, they have nothing to do with games, but the PS3 is a gaming console, and many of us use it as our Blu-ray player.

As an example, when I first tried a movie with my PS3, I could not figure out what buttons on the gamepad controlled the Blu-ray menu.  Would a question like that be allowed?

EDIT

And I just found this [question](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96/non-gaming-gaming-console-questions-allowed/101#101), so I guess the answer is yes.

Comment: What you found is so close that I'm voting to close this.