# Should questions like "How can I install Firefox on the PS3?" be allowed?

Tags: discussion, questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Non-gaming gaming console questions — allowed?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96/non-gaming-gaming-console-questions-allowed)

I don't think that this question (or questions like it) should be on Gaming stack Exchange. Are these questions OK to ask?

[How can I install Firefox on the PS3?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/40055/how-can-i-install-firefox-on-the-ps3)

Comment: _What_ kind of questions? _Why?_ Explain yourself. (Do it by editing the question, please.) In general, [questions about consoles are on topic.](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq#questions)

Comment: @badp wrong, only gaming questions about consoles. please read the FAQ or see that question is closed.

Comment: @IAdapter the FAQ does not say that. Questions about watching Netflix on the PS3 are on-topic.

Comment: @NickT Considering that question is over a year old, I don't see the problem with revisiting the discussion with a new meta post to see if the opinion of the community has changed.

Comment: @Wipqozn this post doesn't present an argument either way, simply asks if this is on-topic.  As it is now, this is an exact duplicate.  If edited to argue against the status quo, sure, it's novel.

Comment: @NickT Good point.

Comment: I've brought this up on SuperUser: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/3804/should-questions-about-using-a-gaming-console-as-a-pc-be-allowed

Answer (score 9):

I answered the question, and I felt it was on-topic.  Console modding has been discussed in the past, and allowed.  This is just an extension of that.  The real question he was asking was along the lines of:

"Can I modify or install different software on my PS3 than what it came with?"

which I think is a valid console-mod related question.  It's also part of what the PS3 was designed to do when it was first built.  Sadly, the functionality was removed.

Had he been asking:

"I installed linux on my PS3 and I'm having problem xyz"

that might be a better question for another site, one that deals with Linux installs and debugging.  But there is at least one other question on this site that covers a very similar topic and was answered + left open:

[What is the PS3 Jailbreak?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8216/what-is-the-ps3-jailbreak)