# Can you ask questions about game systems or only about the games themselves?

Tags: discussion

I was going to ask a question about gaming systems and thought that if it wasn't normal it would get a lot of down votes, so I decided to ask.

Comment: Questions like this have been successful in the past.  Examples: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/86830/should-the-red-light-on-my-nes-flash-when-no-cartridge-is-inserted http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/23340/why-doesnt-duck-hunt-work-on-plasma-or-lcd-screens http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/18358/what-are-the-differences-between-sega-mega-drive-and-genesis-their-cartridges-a Generally if it's an error-related problem, and you provide plenty of information on how it happened, we can at least try to help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In general it's fine, but it depends on the specific question.

From [our "what is on topic" help page](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> If your question generally covers things such as [...] Game-specific hardware and utilities [...] then you are in the right place to ask your question!

You can also see this related topic: [Non-gaming gaming console questions -- allowed?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96/non-gaming-gaming-console-questions-allowed)

In any case, if you're not sure if the question is okay or not, just **go ahead and ask it** - if it won't be accepted you might get some feedback on how to fix it, and at worst it will be closed. And if you truly care about downvotes you can just delete the question afterward and get the reputation you lost back.

Answer (score 7):

Generally, yes, though your question will still need to meet all the other requirements (not subjective, not a recommendation and so on).

From the [help section](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> Game-specific hardware and utilities …